# MySQL select table_name, table_shema and table_id in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've try this query :

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME, i.TABLE_ID, i.NAME 
FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLES i
INNER JOIN information_schema.TABLES t 
ON  (t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '/' + t.TABLE_NAME) = i.NAME 
ORDER BY t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME;
```

but it create a bunch of duplicates.

EDIT : Need to use de CONCAT() fonction...

Comment: Perhaps not the best solution, but would using `SELECT DISTINCT` fix the duplicate problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using DISTINCT function in SQL will give you unique values of each of the variables you used SELECT on.
Read more about it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

and to answer your question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME, i.TABLE_ID, i.NAME 
FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLES i
INNER JOIN information_schema.TABLES t 
ON  (t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '/' + t.TABLE_NAME) = i.NAME 
ORDER BY t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME;
```